# How to connect Excel with locked Access database using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, connect, password-protection

I have an Access database with password ("1234") and I want to connect an Excel file, using VBA, to extract data.

If I unprotect the Access file I can connect with something like this

```
path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\KCBD.accdb"
cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & path & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open cs
```

When I protect Access file with a password I don't know how to do the connection.

I tried

```
Ruta = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\KCBD.accdb"
cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Ruta & ";Persist Security Info=False;" & "Password=1234;"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open cs
```

In the `Cn.Open cs` line this error makes me stop:

> Runtime Error '-2147217843 (80040e4d)'

Comment: Username is missing?

Comment: There's no username, I've locked the database opening it in exclusive mode and Encrypt with password, in the File Menu of Access, entering a password and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in this question: [Excel ADODB VBA error msg 'Not a Valid Password'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037493/excel-adodb-vba-error-msg-not-a-valid-password)

*In Access 2010 the encryption method changed for database passwords, and the ADO provider's "Jet OLEDB:Database Password" keyword does not appear to work with the new method. Here, I had to remove the password, go into Access->File->Options->Client Settings->Advanced and check "use legacy encryption", then recreate the password.
I do not know if there are any new OLE DB connection string keywords for the ACE provider or whether this problem also occurs when using ADO.NET*

Thanks to **bibadia** user

Answer (score 1):

For secured or password protected Access database use property "Database Password"
For Example:

```
cs = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & App.Path & "\myAccessFile.accdb;" & _
    "Jet OLEDB:Database Password= 1234"
```

here "App.Path" is for where your Application is placed you can place Access database however if there is a specified location then replace App.Path with it in your format
e.g:

```
    Ruta = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\KCBD.accdb"
cs = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & Ruta & ";" & _
        "Jet OLEDB:Database Password= 1234"
```

if this wil not work then please try another Jet provider

```
cs = "provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;" & _
```