# Not able to connect to MDB from VBA after setup a Password

Tags: vba, excel, database-connection

I have a MDB connection in my VBA (Excel) without a password which works fine but I decided to setup a password in my MDB file and then I wrote the password in the connection code but it is not working! I am getting a message:

"Cannot start your appliaction, The workgroup information file is missing or exclusively opened by other users"

I am trying to find a solution googling it but nothing works for me. Does someone know how to resolve it

Here is the code:

```
Public Function OpenMDB(ByRef MDBname As String) As Variant

Dim DBConnection As ADODB.Connection

On Error Resume Next
Set DBConnection = New ADODB.Connection

With DBConnection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Mode = adModeShareDenyNone
    .Open MDBname, UserId:="Administrador", Password:="ABC123", Options:=adAsyncConnect
End With

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set OpenMDB = Nothing
    MsgBox "Error on DB", "Error to connect"
    End
Else
    Set OpenMDB = DBConnection
End If

End Function
```

Just to clarify, the MDBname has the path of MDB (and it's correct)
UserId:="Administrador" - Administrador is the Administrator (in portuguese)

Please! I need to resolve it! :S

Comment: Make sure you don't have it open. Having a database open and opening a query from it is a flip-coin.

Comment: It's not open :/ I also restarted my computer to make sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than the With method, try using a connection string. See [three possible methods](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/191754).

```
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source Name=" & MDBNAME & ";" & _ 
          "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=ABC123"
DB.Connection.Open strConn
```

A few other suggestions:

In the older MDB databases, security levels were a feature, specific to user work groups. Be sure you set your database password at the whole file level and not a user group level, with possibly the Administrador user.

Check 32-bit/64-bit level [OLE/ODBC drivers](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-97/) on your machine. Finally, consider changing Provider to earlier Jet.OLEDB version. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037493/excel-adodb-vba-error-msg-not-a-valid-password).

Comment: Thanks Parfait, but when I changed to Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.9 I am now getting: "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed". Do you think it is a reference that I am missing?

Comment: There is no 4.9 version, but 4.0. If this is a comment typo, try `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo but just here on the forum, on the code was right. I changed to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 and it's working now! Thanks a lot Parfait!