# Cant figure out how to write a connection string that allows excel to transfer data to a password protected Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to send data from my excel file to access. It worked perfectly until I wanted to try and secure the database by putting a password on it. Now I just keep getting "Not a Valid Password".

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
Dim dbPath As String
Dim pword As String
Dim strcon As String
Dim X As Long, i As Long
Dim nextrow As Long

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 'add error handling
 'On Error GoTo errHandler:

 'Variables for file path and last row of data
 dbPath = Sheet1.Range("M5").Value
 pword = "MyPassword"
 strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";" 
& _ "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & pword & ";"
'nextrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Initialise the collection class variable
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

'Check for data
If Sheet1.Range("B5").Value = "" Then
MsgBox " Add the data that you want to send to MS Access"
Exit Sub
End If

'Connection class is equipped with a —method— named Open
'—-4 aguments—- ConnectionString, UserID, Password, Options
'ConnectionString formula—-Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;Key_n=Value_n;
cnn.Open strcon
'two primary providers used in ADO SQLOLEDB —-Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0 —- 
 Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
'OLE stands for Object Linking and Embedding, Database

'ADO library is equipped with a class named Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

'ConnectionString Open '—-5 aguments—-
'Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options
rst.Open Source:="Food_Deliveries", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
Options:=adCmdTable
```

I have tried changing the password multiple times with no luck. The password keeps getting rejected in the code.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037493/excel-adodb-vba-error-msg-not-a-valid-password

Comment: If your db an mdb? I can get code to work only with mdb regardless of encryption method.